# When i build ios application(cordova)

Tags: ios, angularjs, cordova

Refused to load gap://ready because it appears in neither the child-src directive nor the default-src directive of the Content Security Policy.

i am using below meta tag
`<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="img-src * 'self' data:; default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self'  'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; ">`

Answer (score 2):

you have to add `gap:` to your Content-Security-Policy meta tag to make plugins work

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="img-src * 'self' data:; default-src * gap:; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self'  'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; ">
```

Comment: If it helped you, you can accept and upvote the answer ;)